# Gdalwarp with "out of globe" values in sinusoidal projection

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I want to project a global image (source ERA INTERIM) from WGS 84 to sinusoidal, using gdal 1.11 and bilinear resampling. It work fine BUT I have values everywhere on the rectangular extent of the projected dataset when I use the -te option. That is, the values are repeated when the dateline is crossed (e.g values from 179 East are duplicated on the left of values from 180 West).

Is there a trick to make sure that the values are not duplicated on the output image (NoData to the left of the projected 180W and to the right of the projected 180E) ?

The workaround is to create a mask of the globe for NoData, but mabe there is a gdalwarp option for doing this in one step.

EDIT : there was a little extra of 1/2 pixel on the original data set, but I've tried with a vrt of just less the 180 and the problem persisted. It does not solve the problem.

the problem occurs with :

```
gdalwarp -r bilinear -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -tr 463.312716527777752 463.312716527777752 -te -20015109.353999998420477 -10007554.677 20015109.354 10007554.676999999210238 -multi -t_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs" $input $output
```

[image]

but not with

```
gdalwarp -r bilinear -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -tr 463.312716527777752 463.312716527777752 -multi -t_srs "+proj=sinu" $input $output
```

[image]

however, I need to use the -te option in order to force all my output images with exactly the same extent.

Comment: Are the extents exactly at -180 and +180? Or is there a little extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I can't replicate your problem.

I have a 2048x1024px image of Blue Marble referenced to WGS84, and warped it in GDAL with

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=sinu" bluemarble-WGS84.tif bluemarble-sinu.tif
```

and get:

[image]

Comment: thnaks for testing. What is your gdal version? maybe this is a bug of gdal 1.11.1

Comment: same as yours, but I did not select any resampling method.

Comment: the resampling is not the reason for the problem. When I don't specify the extent (-te) I have the no data as expected. The problem is that I wanted to force the extent in order to match another one. Maybe I should try with -tap, but this will be on Monday. May I ask you to try with the -te option if you can reproduce i ?

Comment: What -te did you use?

Comment: -te -20015109.353999998420477 -10007554.677 20015109.354 10007554.676999999210238

Comment: Maybe -tr or -ts fits your needs better.

Comment: do you know if -tap can be used to align at a specific coordinate ? I need an exact extent.

Comment: I get the same results as you with -tr and -ts. Maybe you should ask Even Rouault on the gdal-devel mailing list. He might know some extra options.